# Double increment

Tags: java, for-loop, double, increment

I am try to workout a table like below image. I have tried using for loop but cant seem to get the right outcome.
Can someone help me out here.. Thanks loads!

This my code:

```
double XCor = 10;
double YCor = 10;

double incrt = 0.1;

int j = 0;
while (j <= 10) {
    for (double i = 0.0; i <= XCor; incrt++) {
        System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
    }
    double x = j / YCor;
    System.out.println("Count is: " + x);
    j++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: "*I have tried using for loop but cant seem to get the right outcome*" => It would help if you shared that code.

Comment: please share the code, that you have tried and then probably you can expect a solution

Comment: show us what u have coded

Comment: You need three lines of code for this, two of which start with `for` and the third is a `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (double x = 0.0; x <= XCor; x += incrt) {
  for (double y = 0.0; y <= YCor; y += incrt) {
    System.out.printf("x=%f, y=%f\n", x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using doubles for iteration is bad practice, you'll accumulate error. `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) System.out.format("%3.1f %3.1f\n", i/10d, j/10d);`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, you're right. If the values are relevant to money, we have to use fixed point number, however, in this case, x, y seems to be coordinates in x-y plain, and it would be OK to use double.

Comment: How does that figure into the problem? You are doing iterative addition, that's all it takes to accumulate error.

Comment: If the accuracy is important, you're right, however, in the context of question, it seem not that important.